# DNS resolving timeout

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, dns-zone, tcpip

I have a DNS in Linux Centos 7, and when integrating with Windows Server 2012 R2 it only solves in an inverse way, that is, with its IP address, when I try to resolve directly the server, it takes a long time to respond, I do not know why which I have this inconvenience I thought it was a firewall, but I disabled them both in Windows and in Linux, but the problem remains the same.

nslookup in Windows Server

```
  C:/ nslookup 

  Servidor Predeterminado: www.libelula.com.ec
  Adress: 192.168.10.254

  > 192.168.10.10

   Servidor Predeterminado: www.libelula.com.ec
   Adress: 192.168.10.254

    Nombre: cli1.libelula.com.ec
    Adress: 192.168.10.10

    > cli1.libelula.com.ec

    Servidor Predeterminado: www.libelula.com.ec
    Adress: 192.168.10.254

    DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
    DNS request timed out.  
    timeout was 2 seconds.  
    Nombre: cli1.libelula.com.ec
    Adress: 192.168.10.10

    >
```

nslookup in Centos 7

```
    [root@root named]# nslookup
    > 192.168.10.10 
    Server:     192.168.10.254
    Address:    192.168.10.254#53

    10.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa    name = cli1.libelula.com.ec.

    > cli1.libelula.com.ec
    Server:     192.168.10.254
    Address:    192.168.10.254#53

    Name: cli1.libelula.com.ec
    Address: 192.168.10.10
```

direct zone

```
    TTL 3H  @   IN  SOA  libelula.com.ec. root.libelula.com.ec. (
                2   ;serial
                1D  ;refresh
                1H  ;retry
                1W  ;expire
                3H) ;minimum

    @       IN  NS  libelula.com.ec.
    @       IN  A   192.168.10.254
    @       IN  MX  10 mail.libelula.com.ec.
    www     IN  A   192.168.10.254
    mail        IN  A   192.168.10.250
    srv-dactivo IN  A   192.168.10.253
    cli1        IN  A   192.168.10.10
    cli2        IN  A   192.168.20.20                                                                                   
    cli3        IN  A   192.168.30.30
```

reverse zone

```
TTL 3H  @   IN  SOA  libelula.com.ec. root.libelula.com.ec. (
                2   ;serial
                1D  ;refresh
                1H  ;retry
                1W  ;expire
                3H) ;minimum

@   IN  NS  libelula.com.ec.
@   IN  A   192.168.10.254
250 IN  PTR mail.libelula.com.ec.   
254 IN  PTR www.libelula.com.ec.    
253 IN  PTR srv-dactivo.libelula.com.ec.    
10  IN  PTR cli1.libelula.com.ec.   
20  IN  PTR cli2.libelula.com.ec.   
30  IN  PTR cli3.libelula.com.ec.
```